# Linux auto-generate UID and GID and cause a conflict

Tags: linux, user, avahi

I have an user named "myUser" and UID-GID of myUser is "170". This number is GID of another user named "avahi-autoipd" at the same time. I try seperate this 2 users with usermod and groupmod commands. But there is another problem at this option.

My commands and their outputs like this:

```
[root@myHost test]# id myUser
 uid=170(myUser) gid=170(avahi-autoipd) groups=170(avahi-autoipd),10(wheel)

[root@myHost ~]# usermod -u 666 myUser
 usermod: warning: /var/spool/mail/myUser not owned by myUser

[root@myHost ~]# groupmod -g 666 myUser
[root@myHost ~]# chown myUser:myUser /home/myUser /var/spool/mail/myUser

[root@myHost ~]# ls -lt /home | grep myUser
 drwx------. 16 myUser       myUser         4096 May 29 09:50 myUser
 drwx------.  3        41155        41155     87 Jan  2  2013 myUser1

[root@myHost ~]# id myUser
 uid=170(myUser) gid=666(myUser) groups=666(myUser),10(wheel)

[root@myHost ~]# id avahi-autoipd
 uid=170(avahi-autoipd) gid=666 groups=666
```

This state is not permanent. After like 5 minutes UID and GID of myUser and GID of avahi-autoipd changes to 170 again.

```
[root@myHost test]# id myUser
 uid=170(myUser) gid=170(avahi-autoipd) groups=170(avahi-autoipd),10(wheel)

[root@myHost ~]# id avahi-autoipd
 uid=170(avahi-autoipd) gid=170 groups=170
```

How can I seperate this 2 users and block generate new UID and GID for them?

Comment: N.B.: UIDs and GIDs <1000 are usually reserved for system users. If you have to create a system user, use `useradd --system`. It will select an appropriate UID, usually counted down from 1000.

Comment: Then only solution is delete myUser user and create again it with 1000+ GID and UID, right?

Comment: I can seperate users but the system gives old UID and GID to myUser and UIDs and GIDs of myUser and avahi-autoipd become same value again. Which job can do this?